# Where to input a log expression in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to use a expression from NUKE (to convert an exr sequence from its native format into AlexaLogC. Now ive got an expression from nuke which is the following

```
x > 0.14996582 ? (pow(10,0, (x - 0.385537) / 0.2471896) - 0.0522720) / 5.5555556 : (x - 0.092809) / 5.367655
```

been trying to find a spot to place this inside a FFMPEG filter to allow it to bring my footage to the right starting point so i can apply the lut from on set on it.

Was wondering if anybody here had advice on how to correctly filter this into ffmpeg.

Comment: That expr looks like it works on normalized values. What is the pixel format? RGB 16-bit? pow has three arguments - what is the definition?

Comment: RGB 16BIT yeahw

Comment: Basically need ffmpeg to being it to the alexa color space so i can use a lut on it from DI

Comment: pow has three arguments - what is the definition?

Comment: @Gyan its not HDR

Comment: 2048 X 968 Alexa Scan maybe it is HDR who knows but the whites are blown out and they come in better when i use the alexalogc curve in nuke need that in ffmpeg

Comment: I still need the definition of nuke's 3-arg pow function that is shown here.

Comment: @Gyan where can i get that info ? i just copy pasted the expression from nukes color preferences

Comment: Probably the manual or other Nuke users.

Comment: @Gyan so assuming i get that there is a way to fire this into ffmpeg ?

Comment: yes, using a combination of filters

Comment: @Gyan im looking around now for it

Comment: @Gyan cuz this is just the basic AlexaV3LogC curve from nuke

Comment: @Gyan
http://strattoncamera.com/pdf/11-06-30_Alexa_LogC_Curve.pdf

Comment: I only see two args in `(t > e * cut + f) ? (pow(10, (t - d) / c) - b) / a: (t - f) / e`

Comment: @Gyan yeah i guess thats all i could find on it

Answer (score 0):

This is the original expression to be implemented.

```
x > 0.14996582 ? (pow(10,0, (x - 0.385537) / 0.2471896) - 0.0522720) / 5.5555556 : (x - 0.092809) / 5.367655
```

where `x` is the pixel intensity normalized to [0,1]. `x` is linear, so gamma returns identity.

I'm going to assume the `0` in the pow expression is an extraneous arg since the linked reference at http://strattoncamera.com/pdf/11-06-30_Alexa_LogC_Curve.pdf depicts pow() as having only two arguments. I'm also assuming that the input is 16-bit full-range integer RGB.

```
ffmpeg -apply_trc linear -i in%d.exr
       -vf "lutrgb=r='if(gt(val/maxval,0.14996582),maxval*((pow(10, (val/maxval-0.385537)/0.2471896)-0.0522720)/5.5555556),maxval*((val/maxval-0.092809)/5.367655))':
                   g='if(gt(val/maxval,0.14996582),maxval*((pow(10, (val/maxval-0.385537)/0.2471896)-0.0522720)/5.5555556),maxval*((val/maxval-0.092809)/5.367655))':
                   b='if(gt(val/maxval,0.14996582),maxval*((pow(10, (val/maxval-0.385537)/0.2471896)-0.0522720)/5.5555556),maxval*((val/maxval-0.092809)/5.367655))'"
        out%d.tiff
```

Comment: Thanks for much for helping out @gyan, tried it and its still blown out but seems this is definitely the filter to use, the highlights got completely blown up

Comment: You need to verify range and the expr. How are you viewing the TIFFs?

Comment: doing it in nuke / after effects and i need it to output EXR's not TIFFS but both are ok :)

Comment: FFmpeg does not have an EXR encoder. Are you sure the input is full range?

Comment: i meant to type i want the output to be mov eventually when i can sticth the files but im just viwing the images in after effects

Comment: also yes input is full range as nuke handles it just fine

Comment: I ended up doing it in OpenImageIO, FFMPEG couldn't do the job for me